# Adding item dynamically to recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am building a notepad app. I am trying to add another item to the `recyclerview` as soon as the new note is saved by the user.

```
 public class NotePad extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "key";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_pad);

      final FloatingActionButton button = 
      (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.save_button);

      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           SaveData();
        }
      });
   }

   // To Send Note Title to MainActivity
   public void SendData() {
     EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

     final String str = editText.getText().toString();
     Log.d("Check","str:"+str);
     Intent intent = new Intent(NotePad.this,MainActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, str);
     startActivity(intent);
   }



   // To Save Note Content
   public void SaveData() {
     FileOutputStream outputStream;

     try {
        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        final String str = editText.getText().toString();
        String content = findViewById(R.id.textView).toString();
        Log.d("Test","inside try block");
        outputStream = openFileOutput(str, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(content.getBytes());

        Log.d("Test","save done");
        SendData();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

I am saving a note and sending the title(str) that is to be displayed in `recyclerview` row to `MainActivity` as shown above.

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      Intent intent = getIntent();
      String title = intent.getStringExtra(NotePad.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
      Log.d("Check","title added"+title);
      notes.add(title);
      BuildRecyclerView();
    }

    public void BuildRecyclerView() {
      recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycle_list);

      layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
      recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
      mAdapter = new MyAdapter(notes);
      recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

But whenever I add a new note it overwrites the first entry in the `recyclerview` instead of occupying the next row of the `recyclerview`. This is my adapter code:

```
    public class MyAdapter extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

      ArrayList<String> Notes_list = new ArrayList<String>();

      public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> notes) {
        Notes_list = notes;
      }

      @NonNull
      @Override
      public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
      viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
      }

      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int 
      position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(Notes_list.get(position));
      }

      @Override
      public int getItemCount() {
        return Notes_list.size();
      }

      public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mTextView;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
          super(itemView);
          mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_holder);
        }
      } 
   }
```

Comment: Where is your addNote method?

Answer (score 0):

Because you pass last item to MainActivity and generate a new RecyclerView with passed item. You have to keep notes array on first class and pass whole array to MainActivity with intent.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58250283/sending-and-receiving-arraylist-from-one-activity-to-another

Comment: It does not work . Even if I send the entire arraylist. The arrayList gets over written in Note Activity, when I send data  second time using intent even if I send the entire ArrayList it wont work. I think I can use shared preference to store data of previous arraylist and add it to the arrayList when a new data arrives in main activity ?

Comment: The error you specified will also exist in same way in Note Activity