# Receiving data using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send some data using Intent from my NoteActivity to MainActivity class's method (addNote())

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();





    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    notes.add("sql");

    //Intent intent = new Intent(NotePad.this,MainActivity.class);
    //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,str);
    //startActivity(intent); 

}

void addNote()
{

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    String title = intent.getStringExtra(NotePad.EXTRA_MESSAGE).toString();
    notes.add(title);
    Log.d("Data","inside saveData");
    Log.d("Data","title: "+title);

   }

 }



 NoteActivity
 public class NotePad extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "key";

ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_pad);

    final FloatingActionButton button = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.save_button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           SaveData();
        }
    });
}

public void SaveData()
{
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
        ***Some code***

        SendData();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void SendData()
{
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

  final String str = editText.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(NotePad.this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,str);
    startActivity(intent);

  }
 }
```

When I am reciving the (str) in my onCreate() method as(title) every thing works fine and I receive the data, but when I try to receive the Intent in my addNote() method I dont receive the Intent data

Comment: is mainActivity starting NodeActivity ?
why do you use FileOutputStream in saveData method ? explain more precisely please

Comment: have you call addNote() method from onCreate() method. ???

Answer (score 0):

Call your method addNote() from onCreate method.

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
        ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();





        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        notes.add("sql");

        //Intent intent = new Intent(NotePad.this,MainActivity.class);
        //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,str);
        //startActivity(intent); 

          addNote();

    }

    void addNote()
    {

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        String title = intent.getStringExtra(NotePad.EXTRA_MESSAGE).toString();
        notes.add(title);
        Log.d("Data","inside saveData");
        Log.d("Data","title: "+title);

       }

     }
```

Comment: but why? My Intent call is definitely working i.e my Activity is switching when I am calling intent, but the data is not getting received

Comment: your activity can switch through intent but you will receive data in addNote() method. so to get data you have to call this method from your second activity otherwise no data will return.